# c# Return string of Customer name

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to solve some simple tasks and I find my self stuck in a methode that is supposed to get the name of the next customer from right on the list:

The task:
I am given is a directed graph of Customers, where one Customer has exactly one reference to the next Customer or null if it is the last Customer. An example of such a graph can be seen in the diagram below.
Given such a graph, I need to find the customer int numberFromRight nodes from right in the graph by implementing the IFinder interface.

Here is the code I have been working on

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentCustomer = Customers
            .Create("Kim")
            .Previous("Hans")
            .Previous("Ole")
            .Previous("Peter");

        while (currentCustomer != null)
        {
            if (currentCustomer.Next != null)
                Console.Write(currentCustomer.Person + " -> ");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(currentCustomer.Person);

            currentCustomer = currentCustomer.Next;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Customer class

```
public class Customers
{
    private Customers(Customers next, string person)
    {
        Next = next;
        Person = person;
    }

    public Customers Next { get; }
    public string Person { get; }

    public Customers Previous(string person)
    {
        return new Customers(this, person);
    }

    public static Customers Create(string person)
    {
        return new Customers(null, person);
    }
}
```

IFinder interface

```
public interface IFinder
{
    string FromRight(Customers customers, int numberFromRight);
}
```

I want to write my answer in this method and in example is in the graph below the result for `FromRight(peter, 3)` is Ole.:

```
public class Finder : IFinder
{
    public string FromRight(Customers customers, int numberFromRight)
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, there's no graphi visible "below", although I'm not sure you need it.

Comment: So you're saying that you need to find the Nth customer name going from the end of a directed graph? Meaning that you have to traverse the customer list against the direction the graph goes? So for instance, the 1st customer name would be the last one, the 2nd would be the one before the last one, the 3rd one would be the one before that, and so on?

Comment: Hi Lasse, yes exactly

Comment: Is the aim of the exercise to implement this graph? Just wondering, cos if it's not you might consider using LinkedList<string>

Comment: If you init on using yours it might be wise to upgrade your graph so it knows the head, tail nodes and the number of nodes, so you can more easily work out which one is the end-3 (nodecount-3 noses from head, or tail.prev.prev.prev)

Comment: Add the following code to your `Customers` class and see if they help: `public IEnumerable<Customers> TraverseFromRight() => TraverseFromRight(this);
    private static IEnumerable<Customers> TraverseFromRight(Customers current)
    {
        if (current.Next != null)
            foreach (var node in TraverseFromRight(current.Next))
                yield return node;
        yield return current;
    }
` Then you can use `currentCustomer.TraverseFromRight().ElementAt(2)` (0-based), which should return Ole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution without recursion:

```
    public class Finder : IFinder
    {
        public string FromRight(Customers customers, int numberFromRight)
        {
            return Unwind(customers).Reverse().Skip(numberFromRight - 1).FirstOrDefault()?.Person;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Customers> Unwind(Customers customers)
        {
            while (customers != null)
            {
                yield return customers;
                customers = customers.Next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The task: I am given is a directed graph of Customers, where one Customer has exactly one reference to the next Customer or null if it is the last Customer.

So basically what you have in memory is a linked list. While they have some advantages, they are pretty rarely used outside of tree structures exactly *because* they are a pain to itterate or random access over.

> I want to write my answer in this methode and in example is in the
>   graph below the result for FromRight(peter, 3) is Ole.:

This is recursion, with the number being the recursion depth. Something like this:

```
  public string FromRight(Customers customers, int numberFromRight)
    {
    if(numberFromRight <= 0)
      return customers.Name;
    else
      return FromRight(customer.Next, (numberFromRight-1));
  }
```

I might have a off-by-one error in this. But those buggers are everywhere. And if forget the null check of course. But it should get you into the right direction at least.

Comment: Wouldn't that be "from left"?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Next seems to be right of it. Linked lists are usually written left to right at least. Hard to say without the exampel list.

Comment: That is my point, "from right" is different from "to right". In my ahead, the first customer *to the* right is different from the first customer *from the right*. From the right I read as "from last to first".

Comment: @MishMish Then your exampel question makes no sense. Ole is 1 right of Peter and 2 from the start. I can not figure out where he would be Nr. 3

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Inversing the direciton is pretty easy. But really, we are waiting for a proper requirement + example list.

Comment: I think your above solution makes sense. However, this is the task i was given with all the detials. I didn't create it by my self and that's why i also was confused

Comment: @MishMish Then the tasks makes no sense. In no way of counting I can get Ole to be Nr. 3 of anything or Nr. 3 relative to anything. Except the null at the end, but you can not start itterating/recursing from a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really showed us what you have tried so far here, just giving us the assignment.

So here's the theorical answer :

Use recursion with the following :

- if the next customer doesn't exist, you're at the end of the list, therefore you can return a value straight ahead.
- if the next customer does exist, then the answer is the next customer's answer plus one.